# Is there an only-reporting tool for SCORM data?

Tags: reporting, scorm

I am new in SCORM and I am looking for a tool that takes as an input your SCORM data, in a no-matter way, analyzes it and gives you a report.
I don't care for an LMS or web analytics tool. 
Are there any suggestions?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hi There Konstantina,

Have you looked at [SCORM Cloud](https://cloud.scorm.com)?  It is a lightweight training delivery system that will allow you to upload SCORM, AICC, and Tin Cans easily, then has a built-in reporting tool called "Reportage".  Reportage will help you track status, time, score, interactions...most of the elements people look for when they want SCORM reports.  Within Reportage, there is a home page with some graphical representations of the training data as well as the ability to export your reports as CSV.  If you have any questions about it, please feel free to contact us at support@scorm.com.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already seen SCORM Cloud. I would care more for a tool that I could recommend to my clients, so I could export a file eg. an CSV and they could use it afterwards on their own to get a report.

Comment: Understood.  It sounds like permissions would be a thing that would be important to you and SCORM Cloud does not really have a concept of hierarchical permissions meaning you are either an administrator or you are not.  It could get daunting adding yourself to multiple realms in SCORM Cloud if you have many clients.